# Creating a complete revision table from git for one file

Tags: tables, git, revision-control, gitinfo

Using gitinfo2 (or another solution), can I loop through the list of git tags to create a full revision table for the one tex file I am compiling ?

(if need be, it can be scripted and then integrated at compile stage instead of being a full latex solution)

I searched for that, found gitinfo(2) and/or vhistory, but the first one focus on the *current* revision or state of the document whereas I need the complete list of tags/commits (I would prefer just the tags) so that I have a complete history.

The vhistory package looks just like a table/tabular environnement to me, I don't see the way I can automate that or make it interact with git.

I found the latex-git-log package which looks pretty close, except it does not focus on one file but on a whole depot, which is not what I need now (maybe later).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extend `latex-git-log` to accept one (or more) filenames, to restrict the log to that file (those files).

Just before

```
@lines = reverse capturex(@git_command);
```

add

```
# check for command-line arguments 
if ($#ARGV >= 0) {
    push( @git_command, ("--", @ARGV) );
}
```

For completenes the help text should also be changed.